# Lookup Table Decisions - Lookup Based On Characters In Specific Positions

Tags: t-sql, schema

(I do not know of a better wording for the title, but I am open to any edits on that)

Disclaimer: not in anyway close to being a DBA, but I have at least basic knowledge. I am a software developer that deals with front and back end, and I am using T-SQL.

Say that I am managing distribution center data, and there was a requirement that each product needs a numbering system that identifies specific information, such that position 3 specified category, position 4 specified exception, and position 5, 6, and 7 "could" specify type.

For positions 5, 6, and 7, they are used in order to define the type, where if 5 has a valid type value, then 6 and 7 do not represent the logical type, then if 5 does not have a valid value, then check 6 and so on.

For that example, order is determined by the starting index (5 is first, 6 is second, and 7 is last). An instance has come up where position 6 has a specific value that forces the order to change. Let us say that when position 6 is N, then its order is determined to be after position 7.

- Position 5

  - Order 1

    - A
    - B
- Position 6

  - Order 2

    - 2
  - Order 4

    - N
- Position 7

  - Order 3

    - 1

As far as a lookup table, the current concept is to take the substring of the provided value and use the specified position as the starting index. The idea of a variable length has been reviewed, and the idea has sparked some variations that could be achieved for the "newer" case.

Here are three ideas on usage for the lookup:

1. Specify each index and corresponding value, specify precedence, on joins use ROW_NUMBER in respect to order
2. Specify the base index, specify the value as each possible combination (such as 'BN1' ties to the lookup for position 7, or 'A21' ties to position 5)
3. The same concept as 2, except that the values are stored with regular expressions ('[^AB]N[^1]' ties to position 6)

For idea 3, it seems like an attempt to push the row count down and does not give a whole lot to helping the subsequent queries that could be used for the table.

For idea 2 and 3, the length of the value would usually be 3, so that each position is represented, but when position 5 occurs the length used can be 1.

For idea 1, one of the main queries that I see when using that style of table is to have the ROW_NUMBER being used in a sub-query, then the main query will have a ROW_NUMBER = 1 check to get the lowest order represented.

All three ideas work, and there are not many differences query-wise that I can see. As for the table itself, the differences are mainly in the possible size for the reference values (larger to accept regular expressions or combinations rather than single characters), and a column for order. It is difficult to see if there will be any changes in the foreseeable future where more values or different ordering styles could be added.

I am having trouble seeing where the over-engineering line is for this specifically, since it is a smaller dataset.

As far as the ideas above, are there any pros and cons that are not currently being expressed? For the table and queries that would be used, is there a concept/format with lookup tables that proves to be more self-explanatory?

it is more likely that there will not be changes to the table for some time (decisions made at a much higher level and tend to be slow) and that someone new (to the team or the tables) would be reviewing this table and associated queries.

Here is the rough draft table schema as a script:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductNumberLookup
(
    StartingIndex INT NOT NULL,
    OrderId INT NOT NULL, --This column does not exist for ideas 2 and 3
    ValueLength INT NOT NULL,
    ValueDescription VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    TypeValue VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)
```

I am not necessarily looking for the best practices, and I can see where the above content could be from that side, but I am looking for any perspectives that are being missed when considering design in respect to the ideas specified above. I also do not know if the usage and questions around it makes this mostly subjective. Please let me know if any re-wording will help.

Edit (Requested concrete examples):

Product Id examples:

- BCDS192

  - would give back null since there is no associated value
- DFS2N31

  - would give back the type value associated with position 7 being 1
- SNJ4XN1

  - would give back the type value associated with position 7 being 1 because position 6 has the value making it last in ordering
- CVB2A21

  - would give back the type value associated with 5 being A since it is first in order the other 2 positions are not used even though they have a valid value

As for type value expected:

- position 5

  - when A, get Type Value (future ordered)
  - when B, get Type Value (back dated)
- position 6

  - when 2, get Type value (order/payment in future)
  - when N, get Type value  (re-order/damaged on transport)
- position 7

  - When 1, get Type Value  (re-order/payment in past)

These are arbitrary results, but the outcome follows the pattern.

The query would contain a join similar to this:

```
Left Join ProductNumberLookup pnl
On SUBSTRING (provided.ProductId, pnl.startingindex, pnl.valuelength) = pnl.valuedescription
```

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this; can you give a few concrete examples of product codes and how they map?  Also, approximately how many distinct codes are there?  Note that a join using `SUBSTRING()` generally cannot use indices, but if we can work out a solution using `LEFT()` it should be SARGable.

Comment: I will add that information to the post. The use of substring was mainly a first pass solution, so there may be another method to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I grok the intended results here, but consider these additions:

- A calculated and persisted column on your `Inventory` table (is that a good name for the first table?) on `SUBSTRING(ProductID, 5, 3)`.
- Create the proposed `ProductNumberLookup` table, with a `VARCHAR(3)` for the PK.  Depending on the universe of valid product codes, you may be able to populate this once; otherwise, you may need to check for new codes on a nightly or near-real-time basis.
- Join `Inventory` to `ProductNumberLookup` on `I.CalculatedProductCode = PNL.ProductCode`.  There should be exactly one record in `PNL` for each record in `Inventory`.

Product ID "12345" will have calculated code "5" and match the lookup record "5".  Product ID "1234567" will have calculated code "567" and match the lookup record "567".  The join will be narrow (three bytes, assuming you're just using ANSI for your codes) and SARGable, and the lookup table will be small (no more than ~50,000 records), so this should be fast.

The downside is an extra field in your `Inventory` table, which I'm guessing is very large.  If that's unacceptable, you can refrain from persisting the column, but you'll probably need an index scan every time you join.  I trust that there *is* an index on `I.ProductID`.

---

As far as keeping the `ProductNumberLookup` table populated, that should not be a problem.  Assuming there are only (26 letters + 10 numbers + null) ^ 3 = ~50,000 possibilities, you can easily populate this table with all possible values at creation time.  For any product codes which are not currently valid, set `ValueDescription` and `TypeValue` to "Invalid" or "Unknown".  Any reports which use this table can `INNER JOIN`, confident that there will be a record on the other end.

The nice thing about this approach is that if someone creates a new product code without telling you about it (and you know they will), their reports will still total correctly.

If you choose instead to only populate the table with known good values, you'll need to periodically scan the `Inventory` table for missing values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CalculatedProductCode
FROM Inventory AS I
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ProductNumberLookup AS PNL WHERE I.CalculatedProductCode = PNL.ProductCode)
```

...and insert the resulting values.  However often you run it, there will be a window in which `Inventory` records might have no matching `ProductNumberLookup` record, possibly causing reports to under-count, or NULL exceptions to propagate through your apps.  That might be acceptable if the universe of product codes was huge, but with just three characters I'd stick to populating all 50,000 ahead of time.

Rather than running this scan on a scheduled basis, you could put an INSERT/UPDATE trigger on `Inventory`, to insert the calculated code into `ProductNumberLookup` if it does not already exist.  There would be overhead, but it may be acceptable.

Comment: I believe that I understand what you are saying here, and yes Inventory sounds similar enough for my example, there is an index on that column, and while there are numerous valid product codes the lookup is limited to those positions. That will make the other product codes have a type of NULL, where it is not represented in the lookup, and that is expected. As for the intended result, if a product is set to have a certain typing associated with it, then a query using the inventory data should include/retrieve the associated type, if there is on associated type, then it will be NULL.

Comment: It does feel like that goes with the last two ideas, where the combinations of 5, 6, and 7 are explicit instead of separate rows for each position and value occurrence (Id: CVB2A21; RIGHT(Id, 3): A21; Reference Value: A21; Type Returned: Type Value (re-order/payment in past)). That would also allow me to do a RIGHT(Id, 3) instead of SUBSTRING on the whole value. For new valid values in any position or new positions, wouldn't this be difficult to maintain?

Comment: +1 for ***adding a materialised sort key column*** (OP describes it as a "smaller dataset", though I'm in the dark on what that means in practice :o)).

Comment: @eparham7861: before you write the column with `RIGHT()`, consider if there's any chance that people can populate codes with less than seven characters.  If there's a check constraint looking at the field length, great, otherwise I'd try to plan for failure and stick to `SUBSTRING(5, 3)`.

Comment: @Will Crawford - as far as small dataset, I mean that there is an easily maintainable amount of data that could be kept by hand. (Ex: as easy to keep as 'the type for position 6 can happen when neither value is present in position 5'  or (index: 5, length: 3, reference: '_[2N][^1]'), but I am still gaining different understandings on vocabulary :)

Comment: @Jon currently the Id is restricted to have no less that the indexes shown, but that is not to say that at some point it could be greater as the need arises. It is safe to say that the Id will not shrink, but it is not something explicitly stated in the system of record. The foreseeable items would deal with picking a new character or position and which combinations mean some certain type, such as adding a different valid value for position 5 but it cannot pick that type if position 6 is N.

Comment: If you compute a separate column for sorting, it makes your query simpler (hopefully), and the work only needs doing on insert (or perhaps if you ever update the values used to generate it). So you save a tiny bit on understanding the code when it comes to any kind of maintenance work; and, if you ever need to change it, it's just updating the code for a trigger in the database (and it's easy to recompute the column at that point). If more than one application / service / whatever accesses the same data, you've saved multiple pieces of work and avoid any risk of inconsistency between them, too

Comment: ... should have made this an answer, I guess, but Jon's is thorough :o)

Comment: Yes, it is quite thorough. I didn't get the notification for the edits, and only noticed after I scrolled and notice new words. I feel more confident with that answer, and it allows for better flexibility when the need for future requirements happens.